# How to execute required code when document was ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

#### main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jq': 'jquery.min',
        'init': 'init'
    },
    shim: {
        'init': ['jq']
    }
});
requirejs(['init']);
```

#### init.js

```
requirejs(['func'], function(func) {
    $(function() {
        // Do something when document is ready
        func.doSomething();
    });
});
```

#### func.js

```
define(function() {
    var box = $('.box');

    return {
        doSomething: function() {
            // Do something;
        }
    }
});
```

I required `fun.js` when use `init.js`, which means if I set param like `var box = $('.box')` in the beginning might not get the dom because it's not created, I know I can declare it in `doSomthing` function, but is it possible to declare it to global and let other function in `func.js` can reuse it and make sure it happened after dom is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your module be dependent on the DOM being ready. You do this by using the [`domReady` plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload). Define `func.js` like this:

```
define(['domReady!'], function() {
    var box = $('.box');
    //...
});
```

The exclamation point is not a typo. By requiring `domReady!` you are asking it to work like a plugin, rather than a regular module. This dependency won't resolve until the DOM is ready. Make sure to read the documentation of `domReady`. In particular you may need to increase the `waitSeconds` configuration option.

Answer (score -1):

To execute code after the document is ready, I suggest using an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).

```
(function ($) {
    var box = $('.box');
}) (jQuery);
```

To declare a global variable in javascript, you can attach it to the "window" object.

```
(function ($) {
    window.box = $('.box');
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Given that OP uses RequireJS, neither of your suggestions are good. The last one especially, seeing as one of the goals of using RequireJS is to avoid polluting the global space.